# SecurityContextLogoutHandler clearing Authentication even if set to 'false'

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm currently trying to implement a logout mechanism for our application in Spring Boot 2 with Spring Security.

My logout configuration for spring security is:

```
http
    .logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout.html"))
    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
    .addLogoutHandler(handler1)
    .addLogoutHandler(handler2)
    .clearAuthentication(false);
```

With this configuration Spring adds both handlers to the `LogoutFilter` along with Spring's own `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` as the last handler in the handler's chain.

The problem we are facing is that in our custom `LogoutSuccessHandler` I need to have access to some variables stored in the `Authentication` in the security context but the context is cleared in the `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` even when the `.clearAuthentication(boolean clearAuthentication)` is set to `false`.

What I really don't understand is the implementation of the `logout` method in `SecurityContextLogoutHandler`.

```
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) {
    Assert.notNull(request, "HttpServletRequest required");
    if (invalidateHttpSession) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            logger.debug("Invalidating session: " + session.getId());
            session.invalidate();
        }
    }

    if (clearAuthentication) {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        context.setAuthentication(null);
    }

    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

Even when I set the `clearAuthentication` to false, it doesn't really matter because the last line of the method `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();` will clear it anyway.

What is the point of the `clearAuthentication` flag and how to retain the Authentication if I need to?

Comment: The `Authentication` is passed into the `LogoutSuccesHandler` so why would you need another way to obtain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a look at the source code and docs, and this is based on Spring Security version 4.2.X.

`SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();` does not clear the contents of the context, but removes it from the `SecurityContextHolder`'s holding strategy.
As an aside the following strategies are available:

- ThreadLocal
- Inheritable ThreadLocal
- Global

I'm sure someone will point out where to read up on these different strategies, but it's not really relevant to this answer.

> What is the point of the clearAuthentication flag

The [JavaDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/SecurityContextLogoutHandler.html) say this: "If true, removes the Authentication from the SecurityContext to prevent issues with concurrent requests."

That is to say, it bears little or no relevance to what you are trying to do in this particular case.

> and how to retain the Authentication if I need to?

You implement [LogoutSuccessHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html) where the `Authentication` object is passed directly into `onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)`.
You don't need to do anything fancy else to gain access to the object.